# Error "Attempt to reclose a closed cursor" executing a query using FireDac

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I have a problem with a connection to a database in Firebird 2.0

I'm using Delphi Berlin and the connection is made using FireDac. 
In fact the connection test with the FDConnection1 I do it correctly and if I do a FDConnection1.ExecSQL (v_SQL, []) (where v_SQL I have a delete or an insert, it does it correctly.

The problem appears when I put a fdQuery1 and if I double click on it and on the tab I put a simple query:

```
select * from tipo_cliente
```

then clicking on the EXECUTE button gives me the following error (and I can not find any of it on the internet):

> ```
> [FireDac][Phys][FB]Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -501
> Attempt to reclose a closed cursor
> ```

Of course this query if I take it to some Firebird manager, like IBmanager, works correctly

Comment: it sounds like a FireDac bug if this happens in design time

Comment: Strange, did a test in Delphi Berlin 10.1 (build 9432) and but with FB3.0.4, all went okay.

Comment: `tipo_cliente` might be some complex thing like VIEW, Stored Procedures, Computed Columns or a combination of those. Maybe they have some complex logic inside to run this visibly simple query